# Dropbox permissions issue, elementary OS

Tags: filesystems, file-permissions, dropbox, elementaryos

Using elementary OS Freya x64 on my laptop I wanted to install Dropbox now. I also use windows 8 on another partition, where dropbox was already installed and working. To not waste space I used this guide here http://codeyarns.com/2013/03/17/how-to-share-the-same-dropbox-directory-between-windows-and-ubuntu/

My windows partition is /dev/sdb4 and the entry in fstab looks like this:

```
UUID=B2104BC8104B9271 /media/windows ntfs defaults 0 0
```

But now when starting dropbox via terminal (as myself, not root), I get the dropbox permissions error

```
Couldn't start Dropbox

This is usually because of permissions error. Errors can also be caused by your home folder being stored on a network share.
```

The tmp log file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/iQgiWNEA

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem using this guide here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744078&s=cf13b934efb66f634dd7d8f141e0d9c2&p=10765845#post10765845